# update two layer nested object based on the id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this structure in my `Mother` Model (this is a fixed structure and I just push cards or update them on these 3 array levels):

```
{
  cards: {
    starter: [],
    intermediate: [],
    advanced: [ {Object}, {Object}, {Object} ]
  },
}
```

The `Objects` inside `cards.advanced` array above are like:

```
{
  cards: [
    { // this is a single card object 
      title: 'this is a card',
      id: 'main-2-1' // this is unique id only in advanced array, we may have exact id for a card in starter or in intermediate array
    }
  ],
  unit: 2 // this is the unit
}
```

Assuming I have access to `Mother` model like this:

```
const motherModel = await db.Mother.findOne({}); // this retrieves all data in the Model
```

How can we **update** a card object based on its `id` and the `level` it belongs to and replace the whole card object with `newCard` ?

```
const level = 'advanced'; // the level of the card we want to search for

const cardID = 'main-2-1'; // the exact id of the card we want to be replaced

const cardUnit = cardID.split('-')[1]; // I can calculate this as the unit in which the card exist inside

const newCard = { // new card to be replaced 
    title: 'this is our new updated card',
    id: 'main-2-1' 
}
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
const updated =  await db.Mother.update(
        { ["cards." + level + ".unit"]: cardUnit },            
        { ["cards." + level + ".$.cards"]: newCard }
    )
```

I have tried this one too but it doesn't change anything in the Model:

```
async function updateMotherCard(card, level) {

    const cardID = card.id;
    const cardUnit = cardID.split('-')[1];

    const motherModel = await db.Mother.findOne({});
    const motherLevel = motherModel.cards[level];

    const selectedUnit = motherLevel.find(e => e.unit == cardUnit);

    let selectedCard = selectedUnit.cards.find(e => e.id == cardID);

    selectedCard = card;

    const updated = await motherModel.save();

    console.log(updated);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually sort your problem out with the **update** method, but you have to do it in a different way if you are using MongoDB 4.2 or later. The second parameter can be the `$set` operation you want to perform or an `aggregation` pipeline. Using the later you have more liberty shaping the data. This is the way you can solve your problem, I will breakdown after:

```
db.collection.update({
  "cards.advanced.unit": 2
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "cards.advanced": {
        $map: {
          input: "$cards.advanced",
          as: "adv",
          in: {
            cards: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$adv.cards",
                as: "advcard",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$advcard.id",
                        "main-2-1"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      title: "this is a NEW updated card",
                      id: "$$advcard.id"
                    },
                    "$$advcard"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            unit: "$$adv.unit"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  new: true,
  
});
```

First with use the **update** method passing three parameters:

- Filter query
- Aggregation pipeline
- Options. Here I just used `new: true` to return the updated document and make it easier to test.

This is the structure:

```
db.collection.update({
  "cards.advanced.unit": 2
},
[
  // Pipeline
],
{
  new: true,
});
```

Inside the pipeline we only need one stage, the `$set` to replace the property `advanced` with an array we will create.

```
...
[
  {
    $set: {
      "cards.advanced": {
        // Our first map
      } 
    }
  }
]
...
```

We first map the `advanced` array to be able to map the nested cards array after:

```
...
[
  {
    $set: {
      "cards.advanced": {
        $map: {
          input: "$cards.advanced",
          as: "adv",
          in: {
            // Here we will map the nested array
          }
        }     
      } 
    }
  }
]
...
```

We use the variable we declared on the first map and which contains the advanced array current item being mapped ( `adv` ) to access and map the nested "cards" array ( `$$adv.cards` ):

```
...
[
  {
    $set: {
      "cards.advanced": {
        $map: {
          input: "$cards.advanced",
          as: "adv",
          in: {
            cards: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$adv.cards",
                as: "advcard",
                in: {
                // We place our condition to check for the chosen card here
                }
              }
            },
            unit: "$$adv.unit",
          }
        }     
      } 
    }
  }
]
...
```

Lastly we check if the current card id is equal to the id being searched `$eq: [ "$$advcard.id", "main-2-1" ]` and return the new card if it matches or the current card:

```
...
{
  $cond: [
    {
      $eq: [
        "$$advcard.id",
        "main-2-1"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "this is a NEW updated card",
      id: "$$advcard"
    },
    "$$advcard"
  ]
}

...
```

Here is a working example of what is described:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/xivZGNeD8ng

Comment: This is ruining the data structure of the collection :(

Comment: What do you mean by ruining? It is the same thing with the updated value. Unless your description of the collection wasn't accurate

Comment: You replaced the object returned from `"cards.advanced.unit": 2` with an array right?

Comment: I just checked the example and I had a typo, that's why the output format was wrong. I am fixing now. This should work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gfBBPYW7krm

Comment: I fix the example as well. There was a line `id: "$$advcard"` which was actually `id: "$$advcard.id"`

Comment: Rafael Please look at your playground. the structure of advanced is totally different in updated result... there is no units anymore... inside advanced we should have an array of unit objects and each unit object has cards property which have the card we want to update...

Comment: I thought we can select a single card and update its content, not replacing the whole array of advanced !!  but it seems mongoose is too weak to do a simple task possible with vanilla JavaScript :((

Comment: I got it. Give me a sec to fix it.

Comment: Check it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rSqU2Z69qAY

Comment: Good job but, I think still I can't find the `unit: 2` in the result...

Comment: Look again: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xivZGNeD8ng lol

Comment: Great Job Man , give me a second to try the above snippet in my own code....

Comment: Without you, the world lacked something important Rafael... I study your code to learn it now...