# evaluated the level dynamically inside map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Thanks to  [Rafael Freitas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414776/update-two-layer-nested-object-based-on-the-id) here is my update function of the mongoDB:

```
const updated = await db.Mother.update({
      "cards.advanced.unit": card.unit
    },
    [
      {
        $set: {
          "cards.advanced": {
            $map: {
              input: "$cards.advanced", // I cannot use: ["$cards." + level]
              as: "adv",
              in: {
                _id: "$$adv._id",
                unit: "$$adv.unit",
                cards: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$adv.cards",
                    as: "advcard",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$advcard.id",
                            cardID
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          type: "this is a NEW updated card",
                          id: "$$advcard.id"
                        },
                        "$$advcard"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    {
      new: true,
      
    })
```

I just want to be able to  dynamically evaluated the level of the query so instead of using :

```
"cards.advanced.unit"
```

I can use this:

```
["cards." + level + ".unit"]
```

But when it comes to the sting inside the `map`:

```
$map: {
        input: "$cards.advanced", // I cannot use: ["$cards." + level]
...
```

then I cannot use just: `["$cards." + level]`

The updated collection properties will be inserted into an **array surprisingly!!**

How can I dynamically define the `level` inside that `map`?

Comment: What? I can use all of them without brackets?!!

Comment: Yep, see my answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the array brackets.

```
input: "$cards." + level
```

This is just string addition (adding two strings together).  The array brackets have nothing to do with causing the strings to be added together.  That's just something else you needed in your other context.

As an example, you can just add two strings together and it creates a new string with the combined results:

```js
let x = "two";

let result = "one, " + x;

console.log(result);
```

---

The brackets would be needed if it was in the left side of the object property declaration.  That would be called a computed property name and is a Javascript feature that allows a Javascript expression to be used for the left side of a property declaration.  The brackets allow a Javascript expression to be used in this specific place where an expression would not normally be allowed in the language.  An expression is always allows on the right had side for the property value so the brackets are not used there.  If they were used on the right side, it would be declaring an array.

Comment: I used all 3 without brackets but it's mongodb and it throws error `Unexpected token '+'`

Comment: @SaraRee - Don't go indiscriminately removing the brackets.  You have to know if the brackets are required or not for the database operation you're specifying.  If the brackets were required when you hard-coded the string, then they are still required.  If they were not required when you hard-coded the string, then they should not be there.  The brackets are part of the database syntax, not part of the string addition.

Comment: in JavaScript it was easy but here I don't know seems impossible,

Comment: @SaraRee - - If the string addition is on the left side of an object declaration such as where, `"cards.advanced":` was located, then you have to use the brackets to put an expression there.  If it's on the right side of an object declaration such as `input: "$cards." + level`, then you don't use the brackets.

Comment: Did that it creates new object in the collection!!!

Comment: @SaraRee - To put an expression on the left side of a property declaration, you need the brackets to make it a "computed property name".  That is a specific Javascript feature because normally an expression is not allowed there so the language has this special feature where you put brackets around it to make it into an expression and the result of that expression is used for the property name.  The right side of an object declaration allows an express naturally so no brackets are needed unless you're trying to declare an array.

Comment: I got the idea from your last comment that's right... thanks